# Scheduled Reminders - Renewal Link

Tags: scheduled-reminders

Civicrm 4.7.22 on Wordpress.

Hello,
I copied and pasted the below link into the HTML format area of the scheduled reminders for renewing memberships.  I changed the "myorganization" part to my own domain.  When I click it in the email it will not load a page and even said "Too many redirects".  Am I using this link wrong?  What is the right way to link to the renewal page?

http://www.myorganization.org/?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/contribute/transact&reset=1&id=N&{contact.checksum}&cid={contact.contact_id}

Thank you.

***UPDATE****
The link issue has been resolved. It now works. However, it links to the home page where the header widget and sidebar are visible. I would rather have it linked to a different page where none of that distracting information is visible.  How do I do that?  I don't see an option for overriding the page with the renewal form when I create a new page in wordpress.

****UPDATE***
I resolved the problem. Simply change 
myorganization.org/?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/contribute/…;{con‌​tact.checksum}&cid={‌​contact.contact_id}

to

myorganization.org/civicrm/?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/…;{contac‌​t.checksum}&cid={con‌​tact.contact_id} or whatever url you want the renewal form to appear in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"&id=N": N must be replaced with an integer. View your contribution page and look at the value of id in the URL.

Comment: Thank you.  I did that and the renewal link works now. There is just one problem.  It links to the home page, with the header widget and side bar that only are only visible on my site's home page.  Just the main content area is replaced with the Renewal form.    How do I get this link to go to a different page?

Comment: It is possible to customize a Civi page using CSS and/or custom templates, but first you should view the page while logged out, if that is how your audience will view the page. In that case, the Admin stuff on the screen will not be visible.

Comment: I know how to customize the pages.  That isn't the issue.  The issue is the link does not go to a customized page, it goes to the home page.  How do we get it to go to a customized page?    It is also not an issue of being logged in  I am talking about all the widgets of the home page , that are not part of any other page on my site, are visible after clicking this link. The link seems to go to the home page, I would like it to go to a custom page or even the civicrm page. .

Comment: I found the problem.  Simply change http://www.myorganization.org/?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/contribute/transact&reset=1&id=N&{contact.checksum}&cid={contact.contact_id}  to http://www.myorganization.org/civicrm/?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/contribute/transact&reset=1&id=N&{contact.checksum}&cid={contact.contact_id}  or whatever url you want the renewal form to appear in.  Thank you for your help on the other parts.